# What are the best HTML+CSS compression methods?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, compression

I have an ASP.NET web application and I'm thinking about the following: before sending any HTML or CSS content to users, I wish to 'compress' them, then cache the result and send that to the clients.

I know it is possible to compress these by removing whitespaces, comments and stuff like that, but I'm not really familiar with more advanced solutions for this.

- Apart from this, what compression methods are there and what are the advantages of each of them?
- Does some browsers or the HTTP protocol itself support any kind of compression?

**EDIT:** I'm interested in doing this to dynamically-generated HTML, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gzip` is most commonly used for "advanced" compression (i.e., not just removing whitespace). It is supported by all the major browsers: http://www.gzip.org/. It uses the [DEFLATE algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE). If you only want to *minify* your files, try:

- http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor/ for CSS
- http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html for JS

Or try YUI Compressor or any of the other popular ones.

Comment: So basically you're saying that browsers can decompress gzipped content that is sent to them, right?

Comment: Yes, you should have no problem with modern browsers and gzip.

Comment: Very interesting, I somehow missed this possibility so far. Thank you for clarifying it to me! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can look into any of the minify methods offered by [google](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/), [yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), [microsoft](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/40584) for your javascript and css.  They all do a good job.  Check out [this article](http://coderjournal.com/2010/01/yahoo-yui-compressor-vs-microsoft-ajax-minifier-vs-google-closure-compiler/) for tests on all three.

Additionally, you can have [IIS gzip compress](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true) all your content and even cache it (look at the http headers tab for caching).

Have a look at this [article](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip) for some other ways to speed up your web app also.